# Can you add potentials if charge redistributes?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics, mathematical-physics

Let say we have charged conductor $M$ and we know its potential energy function $V_m(r)$ when $M$ is isolated from any charges. We also have charged conductor $N$ with potential energy function $V_n(r)$ when it is isolated.

Now we put objects $M$ and $N$ close together, the charges on their surfaces redistribute. I am interested in potential energy at every point in space, can I still add potential energy functions $(V_m + V_n)$ to find that?

I'd like to think that it is possible to add functions like that, but I can't find a way of proving it mathematically yet. Any ideas of how to show this?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't add potentials like this, specifically because the charge redistributes.  For an example, let $M$ be a small sphere and $N$ be a large disk.  Let $M$ have some charge.  The potential distribution is the same as a point charge of that magnitude.  If $N$ has no net charge we know the potential distribution from it-zero everywhere.  If we bring $M$ near $N$ it will see $N$ as (almost) an infinite plane and create an image charge on the other side, perturbing the potential distribution considerably.

Comment: An image charge on the other side would be created only if infinite plate is grounded. If N is not grounded, as a positive sphere would be moved close to a plate a negative charge would redistribute in some region on the plate close to the sphere, but there would be a huge region of positive charge on the plate in order to preserve total net charge = 0. The net effect just may be the same as there would be no infinite plane and a charge on the sphere would not redistribute.

Comment: You still have to make the plate an equipotential, which its location was not before it was there.  It will clearly perturb the distribution of potential to do that.  You can view it as an image charge superposed on enough charge on the plate to make the potential correct.